# Mix anonymous and windows authentication for web services in the same directory

Tags: web-services, iis, windows-authentication

I have a web application containing two web services, let's say *PublicHello.asmx* and *RestrictedHello.asmx*.

*PublicHello* must be accessed from anywhere, without requiring login. *RestrictedHello* must be accessed only from domain through Windows authentication (and its behavior is different from one user to another).

In IIS,

- if I enable both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication, then *RestrictedHello* **always shows that the user is not logged in** (even if credentials are correctly send).
- if I enable only Windows Authentication, then *PublicHello* **requires login**.

Is there a way to use different authentication levels for different web services in the same web application/virtual directory?

I imagine it is impossible, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the location element in the `web.config` file. Please see:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx

and

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692(v=vs.100).aspx

To quote:

> By using the location element with an appropriate value for the path attribute, you can apply configuration settings to specific folders and files.